# Deserialize json to bool from int

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there a way to configure deserialization so that when i try to deserialize json with value "1" to be parsed as bool value for an object.

Example class:

```
public class Values
{
    public bool BoolValue { get; set; }
}
```

and the json string:

```
var json = "{\"BoolValue\":1}";
```

When I try to do:

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Values>(json);
```

logically it doesn't work because it expects to receive true or false but receive `int` value

Is there a way deserialize `1` and `0` to bool values???

Comment: The JSON string is wrong and needs to be fixed. JSON supports booleans and `1` isn't a boolean. Instead of trying to cover up the bug, it's better to fix it. If you can't you'll have to create a [custom type converter for that property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Comment: Actually yes, thank you!
Panagiotis Kanavos, i will read about converters. Thank you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom converter

```
public class BoolConverter : JsonConverter<bool>
{
    public override bool Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
    reader.TokenType switch
    {
        JsonTokenType.True => true,
        JsonTokenType.False => false,
        JsonTokenType.String => bool.TryParse(reader.GetString(), out var b) ? b : throw new JsonException(),
        JsonTokenType.Number => reader.TryGetInt64(out long l) ? Convert.ToBoolean(l) : reader.TryGetDouble(out double d) ? Convert.ToBoolean(d) : false,
        _ => throw new JsonException(),
    };

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, bool value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteBooleanValue(value);
    }
}
```

And use it as an annotation:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(BoolConverter))]
public bool Fav { get; set; }
```

Or as an configuration option:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new BoolConverter() },
};
var values = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Values>(json, options);
```